# bypass foreign key constraint in entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a view model that is composed by the following fields

```
public class ProfileViewModel
{

public String description { get; set; }
public Double height { get; set; }
public Double weight { get; set; }

public List<InterestDescription> interestedBy { get; set; }
}
```

**InterestDescription** is another entity that is persisted in my database.

I would like to give the user the ability to create it's profile and add interestdescription **at the same time**.

My problem is that the InterestDescription Entity has a many to one relation with profile so i can't create an interestdescription without having created the profile before .

My question is : Is it possible to bypass the foreign key constraint for a specific insertion in entity framework , if not can you suggest me other workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

And you shouldn't need to. As long as you save the changes a single time, the entities should be created in the database in the correct order.

Comment: ok so i have to store the interstdescription entity inside my session and then use entity framework to both create the profile and add the interest description before i call savechanges . But how can i store the interestdescription in my page and retrieve them when the user has finnished his profile creation ?